Prune this raspberry bush
Imagine a Y shape. The end of the Y goes to the trunk. One head of the Y fruited, but the other just grew at a slow rate. I'm definitely planning to prune the fruiting part of the Y. How much of the Y should be pruned?

That would depend on what you want to do with your raspberry, and what type is it. Some will only produce fruits on last year's growth ("summer-bearing" raspberries), while some others will produce on this year's growth ("fall-bearing" raspberries).
The usual advice on raspberries is to prune dead wood (as the wood will die after bearing the fruits).
For summer-bearing varieties, I tend to top them off at about 1.2 to 1.5m (or about 4 to 5ft), as this will enhance side-shoots production. That's up to personal preferences, habits and context though. If you can, feel free to experiment for yourself :)
As you've posted recently and talked about one head of the Y having fruited, I'm guessing you're having a summer-bearing raspberry.
Pruning should occur late fall or early spring, before next season's growth appears.
All this would also, of course, depends on your climate.
As I didn't remember the English name for "summer-bearing" and "fall-bearing" raspberries, looking for it on Google, I've found this website : https://extension.umn.edu/raspberry-farming/raspberry-types-and-varieties
Looks like there's plenty of informations that might be of interest for you there :)
